# Car Stalls When Coming To Stop

Tags: chevrolet, troubleshooting, stall

A Little Information About Car:

**Make:** Chevrolet
**Model:** Daewoo Joy (local name in Pakistan), Matiz (name in other markets)   1.0 ltr
**Year:** 2008
**KM:** 112500
**Transmission:** Manual

I have a strange, but not unique problem. My problem is similar to [Car Stalls When Coming to a Stop](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3222/car-stalls-when-coming-to-a-stop) and [Car stalls when braking (VW Mk1 Golf)](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/11135/car-stalls-when-braking-vw-mk1-golf) but both related to older models.

**Problem**
In idle position my car runs smoothly and picks the acceleration as expected, but when the car slowed down at signal/speed breaker and clutch is pressed the car starts to stall or completely stalls. I can only avoid the complete stall by applying more gas.

Car does not stall when only brake is applied but When I press the clutch with brake then the car stalls.

**History**
The problem pops out when the acceleration cable was tightened a bit as the car stalling in idle. Later the problem solved but after one day, the car started stalling while running. I visited the technician and he suggested to re-program the complete ECU @ $45 + throttle body cleaning which seem ridiculous as in idle it is alright. By reading the manual http://500.5053.com.cn/daewoo/EN/documents/Matiz/start_matiz.html and some forums, I reset the ECU to let engine re-learn the changes but again after few KM the problem came back.

Please note, there is no "Check Engine Light" and all is working normal.

Is re-programing the only solution OR is this problem related to the clutch?

Comment: I don't think your problem has anything to do with the clutch. I'm not sure reprogramming it would do any good either **unless** there is a technical bulletin on the vehicle ... but if that was the case, the dealership would probably reflash it for free.

Comment: @paulster2, in Pakistan nothing is free. is there any way that it can re-flashed by myself?

Comment: Not without the right equipment, software, and upload file.

Comment: it may have to do with the fuel or ignition. it can also be a problem with the torque converter. The best thing to do is take it to a shop, because it can be a variety of things that is wrong